# trigger method on future date in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using java spring framework to develop a Webapp.
I have a situation where I want to trigger one method at future date( value of the future date is retrieved from database)

I tried spring quartz but it starts running as its xml configuration is loaded and I want to trigger the method only once in the future time.so the date should be able to be set programmatically not from XML configuration

eg

```
methodOne(futureDate)
{
  //on futureDate it calls
  methodTwo(<some args>) 
}
```

What would be the good way to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quartz Scheduler is configurable programatically. I have used it before for user-controlled scheduling, and it can do exactly what you need.

Read all the [tutorial pages](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorial/index.html) (specially the one about [SimpleTrigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorial/TutorialLesson05.html)), and you'll have a better understanding of its capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

did you take a look at the timer api from java se?

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html

here's an example on roseindia:
http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/util/CertainAndRepeatTime.shtml

hope that helped